# Fatal error: Class 'oauth' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\shapeway.php

Tags: php, oauth

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$consumer_key="C:\xampp\htdocs\consumer_key.php";
$access_token="C:\xampp\htdocs\access_token.php";
$api_url_base="C:\xampp\htdocs\api_url_base.php";
$error="C:\xampp\htdocs\error.php";

try {
  $consumer_key="C:\xampp\htdocs\consumer_key.php";
  $access_token="C:\xampp\htdocs\access_token.php";
  $api_url_base="C:\xampp\htdocs\api_url_base.php";
  $error="C:\xampp\htdocs\error.php";
  include "oauth.php";
//***************************************************************************************************

   $oauth = new oauth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, 
   OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);

//***************************************************************************************************

  $oauth->enableDebug();
  $oauth->setToken($access_token, $access_secret);
} catch(OAuthException $E) {
  Error("setup exception", $E->getMessage(), null, null, $E->debugInfo);
}

try {
  $api_url_base="C:\xampp\htdocs\api_url_base.php";
  $error="C:\xampp\htdocs\error.php";
  $filename = "www.sim3dmodel.com/example2.stl";//cube-1cm3-centered_in_meter.stl
  $file = file_get_contents("../models/". $filename);
  $data = array("fileName" => "$filename",
              "file" => rawurlencode(base64_encode($file)),
              "hasRightsToModel" => 1,
              "acceptTermsAndConditions" => 1,
              );
  $data_string = json_encode($data);
  $oauth->fetch($api_url_base ."/models/v1", $data_string, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, array("Accept"     => "application/json"));
  $response = $oauth->getLastResponse();
  $json = json_decode($response);    
  if (null == $json) {
    PrintJsonLastError();
    var_dump($response);
  } else {
    print_r($json);
  }
} catch(OAuthException $E) {
  Error("fetch exception", $E->getMessage(), null, $oauth->getLastResponseInfo(), $E->debugInfo);
}

?>
```

But I get the following error: `Fatal error: Class 'oauth' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\shapeway.php`
If anyone could explain me why I get this error I would be very happy.

Answer (score 1):

Insetead of:

```
$consumer_key = "C:\xampp\htdocs\consumer_key.php";
```

use:

```
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\consumer_key.php';
```

If you have a variable `$consumer_key` in that file you are good to go. I have to say that you need to use a relative path to the file or it won't work. So something like `include 'consumer_key.php';`. If you need a file from a previous folder use `include '../file.php';`. Don't use `\` backslashes for files this will fail. This also includes images etc. You need to do this for every file.

Comment: i edited $consumer_key with include ,but still having the error !! ,could you post the edited version please